# Invert clipping in rgl::clipplanes3d

Tags: r, surface, rgl

As per title.

I'm using the `rgl` package to plot a 3d surface.

At some point I want to clip out part of the plot, and so I use `rgl::clipplanes3d`. It works, but clips out the *wrong* side, leaving in the window just what I wanted to remove (and remove the part I was interested in).

The plane I'm using to clip is defined by:

```
h <- planes3d(a=0.2,b=1,c=0,d=-450)
```

I know it divides the surface into two parts and I want to get rid of one. But if I call

```
h <- clipplanes3d(a=0.2,b=1,c=0,d=-450)
```

the good part disappears and the wrong part stays. Is there some workaround to this, or some transformation I can apply to `a, b, c, d` so that clipping gets inverted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a real question but I got inspired while writing it and I just found a solution.

You just have to apply, pseudocoding, `(a,b,c,d) -> (-a,-b,-c,-d)`.

In other words, as the plane is defined by `ax + by + cz + d = 0`, you can multiply the equation by `-1` and get the exact same plane.
However, using `-a,-b,-c,-d` you'll invert the half-space stripped out by `rgl::clipplanes3d`.